# How to allow Googlebot to Crawl my React App?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I have deployed a React-based Webb app in Azure App Services
The website is working as it is supposed to, but according to https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly, Google is not able to reach it.

Google's guess is that my Robot text is blocking it, but I don't think it is the case

Below is my robot text

```
https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Does anyone know if Azure App Services could be blocking Googlebots by default? If so, how do I whitelist them?

Update: After some investigation, I think Cloudflare is actually responsible for preventing Googlebot from crawling. Anyone knows how to get through the problem?

Comment: This is propably related to this -> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-bot-protection-rule-set-in-public-preview-for-web-application-firewall-waf-with-azure-front-door-service/

Comment: I don't have any WAF-Policies active at the moment though...if it is a default setting somewhere, how do I allow Google through?